# Split a string on whitespace AND a char followed by whitespace again

Tags: c#, string

I need to split a string describing a soccer match into home team and away team.

The string will always be something like "Manchester United v Liverpool".

I need to split on ' v ' - i know that - I just don't know how to do it in C#

I tried

```
 string s = item.Summary;
 string[] teams = s.Split('v');
 tempEvent.HomeTeam = teams[0].Trim();
 tempEvent.AwayTeam = teams[1].Trim();
```

but naturally that made the above mentioned game be between Manchester United and Li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string game = "Manchester United v Liverpool";
string[] teams = game.Split(new[] { " v " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

It will split the string on `[interval]v[interval]`.

So if `game` is `Manchester United v Liverpool` the two strings in `teams` will be `Manchester United` and `Liverpool`.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I tried that first resulting in "Argument type 'string' is not assignable to paramater type 'char

Comment: If so you can select this answer as best :)